# Как прочитать локализированую строку?

Tags: c#, локализация

Создал новый проект в С#, windows forms, поставил label1 на форму написал ему Text: Hello, дальше изменил Language формы на русский изменил Text label1 на Привет, создался файл ресурсов Form1.ru.resx. Как теперь мне получить этот привет програмно? Вопрос в том, как добавить строку самому а не измения компонент для некого языка и потом в зависимости от языка читать эту строку. Как програмно читать String1?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Name: `label1.Text` o_O

Comment: А свою строку как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что Вы делаете не совсем правильно. Дело в том, что при попытке добавить вручную строку в resx-файл для формы возникает предупреждение о том что это делать крайне нежелательно, т.к. может повредить форму (дословно: editing this item could corrupt the project item).

Вобщем если Вам нужно только менять текст лейбла на форме, то ничего вбивать в resx не надо. Дизайнер все сам вобъет. Если же Вы хотите вывести какой-то текст программно (MessageBox или динамический текст на форме), то лучше создать свой файл resx.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp) подробно расписано, как работать со своими resx-файлами.